# Class must be either declared abstract .... ! error

Tags: java, android-studio

I wanted to put a spinner in my activity. Ive done the coding and it shows me a error that - class Profession must be either abstract or implement methods 
 "onItemSelectedListener". But Ive implemented them and checked all the existing cases for this error. Ive even put the code under onCreate(). My code for the activity is posted below

Help me out please. Any help will be very deeply appreciated!

```
package com.appindia.srikavyanalluri.appindia;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
class Profession extends AppCompatActivity implements 
 AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener
{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profession);
    Button clank = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prof);
    final Intent a = getIntent();

    String[] listName = {"<20,000", "20,000 - 30,000", "30,000 - 40,000", ">40,000"};

    Spinner salary = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listName);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    salary.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                                         @Override
                                         public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                                         }

                                         @Override
                                         public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                                             Toast.makeText(Profession.this, "Please Select your Salary Range", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                         }
                                     }
    );

    clank.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                 @Override
                                 public void onClick(View view) {

                                     EditText company = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit5);
                                     EditText experience = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit6);
                                     EditText designation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit8);
                                     Spinner salary = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin);
                                     String item = salary.getSelectedItem().toString();


                                     if (company.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                                         company.setError("Company Name is required!");

                                     } else if (experience.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                                         experience.setError("Years of experience is required!");

                                     } else if (designation.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                                         designation.setError("Your Job designation is required!");

                                     } else {
                                         Intent i = new Intent(Profession.this, Addresses.class);
                                         i.putExtra("comp", company.getText().toString());
                                         i.putExtra("exp", experience.getText().toString());
                                         i.putExtra("item", item);
                                         i.putExtra("desi", designation.getText().toString());
                                         i.putExtra("Name", a.getStringExtra("Name"));
                                         i.putExtra("father", a.getStringExtra("father"));
                                         i.putExtra("gender", a.getStringExtra("gender"));
                                         i.putExtra("home", a.getStringExtra("home"));
                                         startActivity(i);
                                     }
                                 }
                             }
    );

}
}
```

Comment: You're implementing `AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener` in `Profession` class and hence need to override required methods of `AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener` interface. Looking at your code, I don't see a need why your need to implement `AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener`.

Comment: i need to add spinners in code so implemented in my profeesion class. But this code throws me an error that abstract class needs to be implemented. What do i do

Comment: You're adding spinners inside `onCreate` not in class. I think you don't need to implement `AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener`. Try removing that, your code should work fine.

Comment: I tried to delete them . yet the problem persists..Could you please elaborate how can i achieve this ? .Im kinda amateur in this

Comment: Let's discuss in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184317/class-must-be-either-declared-abstract)

Comment: uhhh..i dont have enough reputation to chat

Comment: Instead of `class Profession extends AppCompatActivity implements 
 AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener` use `class Profession extends AppCompatActivity`. Don't change anything else.